# Accessing a value in a user control inside a content page from a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a string (lang) in a user control (ascx) inside a Content Page. I want to access (lang) value from the Master Page. How can I do that?

User Control (lang.ascx.cs) - code behind.

```
 lang = (string)(Reader["lang"]); //lang is retrieved from a database
```

User Control (lang.ascx).

```
<input runat="server" type="hidden" ID="langInput" value="<%: lang %>"/>
```

Content Page (lang.aspx)

```
<uc:lang runat="server" />
```

Now how can I access (lang) value from the Master Page?

Thank you.

Comment: "how can I get (lang) value from the Master Page" you want to assign this value from the MasterPage por you want to read it?

Comment: Read it in order to send it to another User Control on the Master Page

Comment: set this value to some hidden control or session variable and access this in master page Page.Master.FindControl('controlID') or Session["key"];

Answer (score 1):

To find that Control you have to do a lot of `FindControls`

```
//first find the ContentPlaceHolder on the Master page
ContentPlaceHolder contentPlaceHolder = this.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as ContentPlaceHolder;

//then the PlaceHolder on the aspx page that contains the UserControl
PlaceHolder placeHolder = contentPlaceHolder.FindControl("PlaceHolder1") as PlaceHolder;

//then the UserControl
UserControl userControl = contentPlaceHolder.FindControl("UserControl1") as UserControl;

//and finally the Control we want to manipulate
HiddenField hiddenField = userControl.FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;

hiddenField.Value = lang;

//or you can you do the same in a single line of code
HiddenField hiddenField = this.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("PlaceHolder1").FindControl("UserControl1").FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;
```

> If you dynamically add UserControls to the page, do not forget to
>   assign an ID, otherwise FindControl will not work.

```
myControl = (MyControl)LoadControl("~/MyControl.ascx");
//do not forget to assign an ID
myControl.ID = "UserControl1";
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myControl);
```